# iOS ipa for Enterprise project does not open app

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, enterprise, ipa

I am trying to launch an iOS project with an Enterprise account.
First thing first, the project is running just fine when I run it from xcode.
When I download the ipa archive(I created) from the server **it appears to open the app on the screen for less than a second and then immediately closes it**.

I have tried various provisioning profiles:

Development ->  iOS App Development

Distribution -> In House

Distribution -> Ad Hoc

And combined the above with all the possible ways of archiving the project:

-> Ad Hoc Deployment

-> Enterprise Deployment

-> Development Deployment

Only when I archive the ipa for development it works on my phone, as it is registered as development device for this provisioning profile, but not other phones.

Am I missing something out? Is there a setting in Xcode I should change for an enterprise launch?

**UPDATE:** device logs says:

> Dyld Error Message: Dyld Message: Library not loaded:
>   @rpath/ResearchKit.framework/ResearchKit  Referenced from:
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/6DBB2C29-B1AE-4AE0-AEFB-ABF4081467A5/Beck
>   Chestionar.app/Beck Chestionar  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did
>   find:
>     /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/6DBB2C29-B1AE-4AE0-AEFB-ABF4081467A5/Beck
>   Chestionar.app/Frameworks/ResearchKit.framework/ResearchKit: mmap()
>   errno=1 validating first page of
>   '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/6DBB2C29-B1AE-4AE0-AEFB-ABF4081467A5/Beck
>   Chestionar.app/Frameworks/ResearchKit.framework/ResearchKit'  Dyld
>   Version: 390.7
>
> Binary Images: 0x100004000 - 0x100017fff Beck Chestionar arm64 
>   
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/6DBB2C29-B1AE-4AE0-AEFB-ABF4081467A5/Beck
>   Chestionar.app/Beck Chestionar 0x120050000 - 0x12007ffff dyld arm64 
>    /usr/lib/dyld

Comment: do you try to upload IPA in DIAWI.COM with adhoc or distribution provisional profile?

Comment: I tried with AdHoc(from Distribution) and also all of the rest.

Comment: i said how do you try to insatll app? do you try https://www.diawi.com/

Comment: I am using a server form my workplace.

Comment: @asheyla what does console in XCode-Organizer log? You might want to check it to see if the app is crashing or if there is a PP problem.

Comment: i suggest to once test with diawi

Comment: I'm sorry, can't see why diawi would be recommended instead of the server here. Eventually I would have to use the server provided by my workplace.

Comment: You need to take a look at the device console when trying to launch the app.  It will give you the specific failure with the provisioning profile or signing identity that is causing the problem.  Go to

Comment: Go to Window->Devices and select the device you are installing onto.  Try to run the app and see what errors appear in the console.

Comment: see if the ResearchKit framework is visible in the "Embedded Binaries" section of the project settings(General Tab)

Comment: I checked, it is added to embedded binaries. any other ideas?

Comment: `Bitcode` is disabled in build settings and you are testing on a device >iOS8 ?

Comment: Enable bitcode is set to no and yes, I have 9.3.1

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure to select the proper certificate for distribution (in your case that would be the enterprise certificate) and for the provision profile, use "Automatic":

[image]

Once you will set the correct info, you will be able to export an ipa and install it on any device. If app still crash after installing it, then get device logs and post it here so I will be able to tell you what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include ResearchKit in Embed Frameworks area under your Build Phases settings in the project (I believe it is listed as Copy Files in older versions of Xcode):

[image: Example of build settings with another framework]

Make sure you have done this or the compiled binary being delivered to the device will not have the necessary framework files.

If you have that in your project, it could be a trust issue. See [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/1127839/view.html) for information to diagnose and/or fix. Basically, look at the "Check the Signature For a Failure Root Cause" section in this [Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2318/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013777-CH1-ROOTCAUSE).

The link above tells you do to this:

codesign --verify -vvvv -R='anchor apple generic and certificate 1[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.2.1] exists and (certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2] exists or certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.4] exists)' /path/to/the.app

If you get CSSMERR_TP_NOT_TRUSTED as a result of that command, look [here](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG19).

Step 3) was what got it to work for me. Good luck!